# Jekyll Serve not working.Uninitialized constant. Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, cmd, jekyll

I have installed Jekyll on Windows 8 and created a new application. I am inside the directory and it gives me this error when I run `jekyll serve`

```
C:/Blog/> jekyll serve
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/psych_resolver
.rb:4:in `<class:PsychResolver>': uninitialized constant Psych::Nodes (NameError
)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/p
sych_resolver.rb:2:in `<module:SafeYAML>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/p
sych_resolver.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/l
oad.rb:131:in `<module:SafeYAML>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/l
oad.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll.rb:26:i
n `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_requir
e.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/bin/jekyll:6:in `<
top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Here is my `_config.yml` file

```
# Site settings
title: Your awesome title
email: your-email@domain.com
description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
  Write an awesome description for your new site here. You can edit this
  line in _config.yml. It will appear in your document head meta (for
  Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description.
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog/
url: "http://yourdomain.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
twitter_username: jekyllrb
github_username:  jekyll

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
```

Thanks if anyone can help!

Answer (score 4):

run `gem cleanup` it should solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me I fixed it by doing this:

First list your gems `gem list`

```
...
    pg_search (0.7.9)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    posix-spawn (0.3.10)
    power_assert (0.2.2)
    psych (2.0.5, 2.0.0)
    pygments.rb (0.6.2)
    rack (1.6.0)
    rack-cache (1.2)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
...
```

Where you see psych, try using psych 2.0.5 `gem uninstall psych -v 2.0.0`
If you get an error message than uninstall gem 2.0.5 instead `gem uninstall psych -v 2.0.5`

Try Jekyll. This worked for me. You need to find the version of psych that interacts with your Ruby setup correctly. In my case was 2.0.0 but could be different for you.

Comment: Thanks. This resolved my problem. Ended up doing this - 

    `gem list`
    >> psych (2.0.8, 2.0.15)
 and then -
    `gem uninstall psych -v 2.0.15`

Problem solved.

Comment: This one is a much better answer and I had the same problem but uninstalled the earlier version of pysch and job done.

Comment: Thanks Amit, I edited the uninstall commands. They were shorthanded.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bundle exec jekyll serve` in some cases this will solve your issues.